# Click sub-subcommand

Tags: command-line, python

I want to create a python CLI script with the [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/) package.

I looked at the documentation, but couldn't find out how to create a command with subcommand and sub-subcommand like this:

```
cmd subcommand sub-subcommand <options> <args>
```

An idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Groups can be infinitely nested.

Comment: Comparing to the question the use of word "groups" is unclear. Can you please clarify it? Other than that, as you've found a solution to your problem, please feel free to [accept your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). This will mark it as solution, and lift it out from the "Unanswered" queue. Please note that you will have to wait for 48 hours before you can accept the answer.